# VLC live http streaming to Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, vlc

I'm trying to do http live streaming from VLC to an android app using VideoView.

I have 3gp video and use vlc to stream it:

```
cvlc -vvv video.3gp --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,‌​dst=128.0.0.6:9090/jlanza}'
```

In my android I set the videoview source to http:// and to httplive:// but nothing is displayed. I always get an error.

Can anybody explain to me how to configure vlc for http live streaming?

Edit: Solution to my problem

```
cvlc -vvv video.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=:9090}'
```

then the url is http://@server:9090

Comment: HTTP live streaming is only supported in Android 3.0 and above - what handset are you testing this on?

Comment: Mine is 2.3.4 :( I'm also getting :NuHTTPDataSource(4358): Server did not give us the content length!     Is it the vlc command I put above valid for a 4.0?

Comment: @lxt, HTTP live streaming is supported since 2.3.3, I have written app targeting on this, there is even [third party library](http://vov.io/vitamio/) support HLS on 2.1+.

Comment: @jianza, what you asked is not related to HTTP Live Streaming, it is just a regular [HTTP streaming](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer)

Comment: Hi Jlanza , I am facing same problem , can you please provide solution for me

Comment: @sravankumar below in the answer you have what I did. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi i dont wat static video , i have to Communicate Live Video  if possible give ur mail id .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution to my problem

cvlc -vvv video.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=:9090}'

then the url is http://@server:9090